# Network-Manager restart impossible

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager, internet-connection

```
~$ service network-manager restart 
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.77" (uid=1000 pid=10033 comm="stop network-manager ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.78" (uid=1000 pid=10030 comm="start network-manager ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

Any hints? The common network problem in Ubuntu 12.04 with hang up within a couple of minutes.

With sudo I can restart the network-manager but it doesn't have effect to the connection.

Comment: Sorry for pasting without sudo. But I have already done so. No effect with sudo as well. The connecting only reappears after rebooting the whole system. Log attached above.

Comment: You've marked [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/156190/22949) as accepted, but your comment makes it sound like the problem isn't solved for you. If that's the case, you may want to unaccept the answer and/or post a comment on it ...or, if the answer helped you with your initial problem but now you have a different one, the best thing to do would be to post a new question.

Comment: Reported the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1059452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need root level permission to execute this command.

Try

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And then type your password when requested.

Comment: It was happening to me even when using sudo :( Had to restart to make it work.